# php code string response from server and evalue with eval

Tags: php, eval

I am trying to secure the code a bit, for this I make a request to an external server and I respond with php and html code, then interpret it with the eval function of php. The problem I have is that I'm not reading the variables.

I put the code to make it look better.

Code External server:

```
  function response(){
    $json              = array();
    $json["result"] = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset='utf-8'>
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo \$assets?>editor/editor.min.css?v=<?php echo rand(1,1200)?>' type='text/css' media='screen' charset='utf-8'>
   <?php  do_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', $hook_suffix ); ?>
   </html>";

    $response       = new WP_REST_Response( $json );
    return  $response;
    exit;
 }
```

Request

```
$assets ="http://www.external.com/uploads/";
ob_start();
eval("?> " .$request->result);
$html = ob_get_clean();
echo $html;
```

For what I do not understand is that the variable "assets" does not interpret it and does not show its value to me.
Another doubt I have if I also have to put "\" in front of the functions just like I do with the variables.

Thank you!

Comment: the definitely best way would be **not to use eval** altogether! whatever you are trying to do, there *is* a better solution than using eval.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann  What is the best solution? Since you have hacked my code several times.

Comment: that completely depends on what you even want to *achieve* with this.

Comment: nooooooo.. what are you trying to achieve with *what you are doing in the first place*?